# Technical details behind how a malware-infected device infects other devices on the same network?

Tags: network, malware, wifi, attacks, wireless

I'm a security student and for one of my projects, I'm trying to learn the technical details behind a malware-infected device infecting other devices on the same network. I can see so much content everywhere stating that it happens, but I cannot find exactly how does/could it happen? The scenario I'm trying to examine is that the attacker has access to the same wireless network and can intentionally connect a malware-infected device to it but I'm not really sure what makes it spread to other devices.
Any help towards the more technical side of this would be really appreciated :)

Comment: Network infection (as with all infection) is dependent on what the system is vulnerable to. The malware is just exploiting security weaknesses via its payload.

Comment: Thanks for the insight @Nelson. If we have a WPA2 secured Wifi and an attacker sitting with a malware on our Wifi network, what kind of vulnerabilities can he exploit to infect other devices on the network as well?

Comment: The usage of something like "WPA2" and then talking about a networked device shows that you really don't understand the different components of security here... WPA2 deals with external access; people that don't have your WiFi password. A system already connected to your WiFi will not be impacted by WPA2 at all, and WPA2 has nothing to do with dealing with malware on the network.